# Envio de sms por Java

Tags: jsf, primefaces, hibernate, java

Fala pessoal, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação financeira que me foi solicitado ao finalizar uma lançamento, seja feito um envio de sms para o administrador principal. Estou utilizando Java web, Mavem,jsf, Hibernate.   Alguem poderia me dar uma luz.   Obrigado.

Comment: Seria importante [edit] a pergunta e especificar que tipo de hardware será usado para envio do SMS. Se for enviar por software, aí depende de consultar a documentação específica do provedor de serviços.

Comment: Bom dia, Silvano, existe várias APIs para envio de SMS disponível na internet. Eu sempre usei à API Zenvia, ela é simples e fácil de configurar. A API não é free, segue o link da documentação: http://docs.zenviasms.apiary.io/#introduction/tabela-de-status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Procurando aqui pelo Google, encontrei essa implementação aqui:

```
package br.com.meupackage;
import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException;
import org.apache.commons.mail.SimpleEmail;
public class MailService {
    private final static String userAuthentication = "exemplo@gmail.com";
    private final static String passwordUserAuthentication = "123456";
    private final static String sender = "STAFF@L2POG.COM.BR";
    private final static String smtp = "smtp.gmail.com";
    private final static boolean authentication = true;
    public static void sendMail(String message, String subject, String receiver)
            throws EmailException {
        SimpleEmail email = new SimpleEmail();
        email.setHostName(smtp);
        email.setAuthentication(userAuthentication, passwordUserAuthentication);
        email.setSSL(authentication);
        email.addTo(receiver);
        email.setCharset("UTF-8")
        email.setFrom(sender);
        email.setSubject(subject);
        email.setMsg(message);
        email.send();
        email = null;
    }
}
```

É necessário adicionar no `pom.xml` a dependência da lib [Apache Commons Email](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/).

Fonte: http://www.guj.com.br/t/enviar-e-mail-jsf/186408/8

Comment: O que isso tem a ver com envio de SMS?

Comment: Nossa, confundi total SMS com email no momento de pesquisar, vou remover a minha resposta. Valeu pelo aviso!

Comment: @jbueno, consegue remover a minha resposta?

Comment: Não consigo. Só o Autor da Pergunta e os moderadores podem fazer isso.

Comment: Será usada alguma url específica para que o envio de SMS seja feito através desta url? Exemplo: 192.168.1.88+ String+55+DDD+Telefone

Comment: @WagnerFilho Não existe envio de SMS na resposta. Ela faz envio de e-mail.

Comment: Isso! @WagnerFilho, eu respondi errado! Estou saindo do trabalho agora, chegando em casa eu faço um teste para o envio de SMS e posto aqui a resposta correta. Foi mal galera! :(((((

Comment: kkkkk Mas valeu pela dica mesmo não sendo o que queria  kkkkkkkkkkkkk    Obrigado.

Comment: Ficou pendente de apagar e não foi até hoje!?